# Add list of css classes in HTML with Mustache

Tags: html, css, loops, mustache

I'm trying to render the HTML attribute `class` using Mustache. The HTML I'm look to generate is something like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="single-class">First item</li>
    <li class="two classes">Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

From an array like

```
array(
    elements => array(
        array(
            class => array(single-class), // maybe even just: class => 'single-class'
            content => 'First item',
        ),
        array(
            class => array(two, classes),
            content => 'Second item',
        ),
        array(
            content => 'Third item',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I have tried something like

```
<li{{#class}} class="{{.}}"{{/class}}>
```

but that will generate several `class` attributes. I am looking for something more like "if the value exists, join the elements using spaces and put them here".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about `<li class="{{#class}}{{.}} {{/class}}">`?

You would render something like

```
<li class="single-class ">...
<li class="two classes ">...
```

This should fit your need, despite the extra white space at the end of the class attributes.

Comment: If you do not want an empty class attribute, wrap the whole attribute in a boolean section. Check the documentation of your Mustache implementation to know if you need to add a specific boolean key to your items, or if you can query the length of the array right from a Mustache tag. And there you go, problem solved.

Comment: But it would be somewhat useless, since an empty class attribute has no undesired side effect. The initial solution I proposed you already fulfills 100% of your needs.